# JavaFX custom control use method

Tags: java, javafx

I made a custom control `CustomControl` in JavaFX.

The `CustomControl` is basically just a button and a text field. It is made of a `CustomControl.fxml` and a controller `CustomControl.java`.

I also have a view `TestView.fxml` which includes the `CustomControl` with a controller `TestController.java`. The `TestView.fxml` has a button. When that button is pressed it calls the method 'OnButtonPress' from the `TestController.java`. Now in that method I would like to call the method `setText` from the controller `CustomControl.java`.

Now I'm facing two problems.
First: I'm getting the exception 'Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.'

Second: I don't know how to call the method `setText` from my custom control.

Here's the code:

TestView.fxml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="controller.TestController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <fx:include source="../custom_control.fxml" fx:id="custom_control"/>
      <Button onAction="#OnButtonPress" fx:id="button" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="117.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

TestController.java:

```java
package controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class TestController {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private VBox custom_control;

    public TestController() {
    }

    @FXML
    private void OnButtonPress() {
        // that is the method I would like to call
        custom_control.setText("This is the new text");
    }
}
```

CustomControl.java:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class CustomControl extends VBox {
    @FXML private TextField textField;

    public CustomControl() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("custom_control.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();            
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        textField.textProperty().set(text);
    }
        
    @FXML
    protected void doSomething() {
        textField.textProperty().set("The button was clicked");
    }
}
```

CustomControl.fxml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"> 
    <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
    <Button text="Click Me" onAction="#doSomething"/>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: It’s not really clear what you mean here. What you say is the “custom control” is an fxml file which defines an `AnchorPane` and its child nodes. I don’t see the method you are trying to call defined anywhere. Is there a `GuitarSpecTableController` defined anywhere?

Comment: @James_D the ```GuitarSpecTableController``` is the controller of the fxml file. The method I'd like to call is the ```ini``` method which is part of the ```GuitarSpecTableController```.

Comment: Provide the FXML for the `HomeController`.  It should import `GuitarSpecTableController` and use that instead of `AnchorPane`.  See: [Example 4-8 Using an Instance of the CustomControl Class in Markup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm#BABDAAHE).

Comment: I don’t understand how you are using `setRoot(…)` without `<fx:root …>` as the root element of the FXML. Doesn’t that produce a runtime exception? Create and post a [mre] (write a new project from scratch that has just enough to reproduce the issue - including a custom control with a method you want to call - and no more, and post the entire new project here, instead of portions of your actual project).

Comment: @James_D okey, so I made a minimal example like you said. I wanted to thank you for being so patient 

Comment: Instead of `<fx:include>` you should just use `<custom_control/>`. You should, and may actually need to in this context, use proper naming conventions. I think the `FXMLLoader` can only recognize you are referring to a class if the capitalization is correct. (You’ll also need the import in the FXML file.)

Comment: @James_D I finally made it work, thank you so so much. Hope you have a great day 

Answer (score 2):

Okey so I figured out why I didn't work so I though I'd share what problems I had.

1. the name's of the packages have to start with a lower case letter not upper case
2. The names of the Classes as well as the views (FXML files) have to start with a upper case letter.
3. instead of `<fx:include>` you should use the actual tag of the control (in my case `<CustomControl>`) and import the FXML file

When doing all that it finally worked.